# Why are my TrueType hints ignored?

Tags: pdf-generation, truetype, reportlab

I have integrated some hints (a prep handler to update the cvt and glyph instructions (simple MIAPs to copy the cvt values to specific points) into a custom TTF font.

I changed the fonts via Python fontTools.ttx

The font and the hints work perfectly when I test the font in TrueTypeViewerQt.

The font (and the hints) work also in PIL.

I can also see the hints in FontForge (for prep and the glyphs), but debugging them just shows "".
I also get this message in the console window:

```
SplineFontPieceMeal() going unhinted...
```

When I now use the font from a PDF file (written via reportlab), the font is used, but my hints seem to be ignored by Acrobat Reader, Ghostscript, mudraw, Chrome Web Browser (integrated PDF view), or an own application based on PDFium.

Then font exported from the PDF (via mutool) still contains the hints which work in TrueTypeViewerQt.

PDF: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qn3iooazsq1z2w5/d85.pdf?dl=0

Font: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p6qwug9h6vcgps0/testbar.ttf?dl=0

Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to provide the font file and the PDF file for some qualified input.